# How to get all questions related to a tag, using the stackr library?

Tags: r, stackexchange-api

I would like to retrieve all question asked for a specific tag. Specifically for every question: all tags, date posted, body, user who posted the question, and votes.

I tried this:

```
library(stackr)
test <- stack_tags("r","questions", num_pages=1000000, pagesize=100, filter="withbody")
```

but it is not the appropriate query. How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want question data, you need to use the `stack_questions` function, not `stack_tags`.  Also, the `withbody` filter will not get all that you say you want, so you need to use a [custom filter](https://stackapps.com/a/4491/7653).

Something like this should work:

```
library(stackr)
test <- stack_questions(tagged="r", num_pages=10000, pagesize=100, filter="!UHY-aKsFJ(KvceZ5uauvQDp9b_ZwAQaEY0KwVy4Czncd97-22tonZWvDXfhmP(X*Baz8J0uC0Q")
```

Notes:

1. Reference [the `/questions` doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions).
2. There is no point in setting `num_pages` > 10000, since that's your max quota.
3. The filter listed is a custom one that returns the fields you requested.